# Name of 60s/70s American sci-fi TV series about "Central Control"

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to identify a TV sci-fi series that I watched as a kid in the 1970s. The central character was a field agent for a government organisation and the twist was that he was monitored remotely from a control complex called something like "Central Control" or "Central Command". It had a similar feel to Person of Interest: the lone agent battling the forces of evil with the assistance of a backup team.

My memory of it is really vague but bits I do remember:

- It was a US show, imported to the UK
- In colour, I *think*
- It was shown weekly in the UK, so it must have been a series
- Probably an hour long rather than half an hour
- It used an urban US setting
- The command centre was called "Central Control" or "Central Command"
- The monitoring included heart rate, brain waves, etc. and possibly 2-way communication.
- For a long time I thought the chief scientist at the command centre was played by Burgess Meredith but I now think it was actually someone similar. I might be conflating the actor with Whit Bissel in Time Tunnel though.

Any suggestions gratefully received. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are remembering "Search". It did have Meredith in it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_(TV_series)

All the elements you describe are present. It seems to have only lasted one season.

From the wikipedia article:

> The series centers on World Securities Corporation, a high-tech international private investigation company that employs field operatives—the elite of whom are aided by implanted audio receivers and who carry Scanners, tiny video camera/telemetry units which can be attached to tie clips or other jewelry. The most common method is to wear the Scanner on a ring, enabling it to be discreetly aimed.
>
> Each episode features one of three primary agents on a particular investigation, which often have political or organized crime elements.

Comment: Hi Organic, thanks for the fast response and I'm sure you're right because I can remember the scanner devices, now I've been reminded. This has been bugging me for years and I was starting to think I'd dreamed it because nobody I asked had the slightest recollection from my vague descriptions, so I'm glad you've provided an answer at last. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to help out! If you're satisfied with the answer, please mark it as correct by clicking the gray checkmark beside it.